# Indents inside textarea placeholder code are showing on html page

Tags: html, textarea, placeholder

I've been trying to get this big text inside the placeholder to be indented **inside the code only**. But as I try to indent it, the code gets the indentation as literal inside the quotes.

```html
<div>
    <textarea name="details" required id="details"  class="largeText" placeholder="The student 
        claimed that he/she is the reincarnation of Don Quixote de La Mancha and attacked the 
        Instructor claiming that the later resembled a giant.">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

[image: As you can see, the text area take the text indentation as literal]

I usually would not care much to have a disproportional big line on the HTML code, but this is for class and I am rather curious now.

Comment: Have you tried to set rows and cols to your textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `indent` inside a block of attributes and sometimes elements. Because a little space can also make huge differences.

See in the below snippet a break of line after end of `span` make a difference of space when it is not braked.

> It is safer to break after the end of element or at `<>`(but not applied in all cases like in `text-area` breaking after `<>` will not display place-holder) arrows because sometimes space matters

```html
 <div>
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>1</span><span>2</span>
</div>
```

A space between `span ::after` doesn't apply the style in below snippet

```css
div span ::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto 30px;
  width: 20%;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #5d9cd4;
}

.second span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #5d9cd4;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

So don't use unnecessary spaces in-between

```html
<div>
  <textarea name="details" required id="details" class="largeText" placeholder="The student claimed that he/she is the reincarnation of Don Quixote de La Mancha and attacked the Instructor claiming that the later resembled a giant."></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: So, this is how my code is right now. I just wanted to make it multiple lines so it looked better, having the whole code on view instead of one line spaning all the way to the right.

Comment: To be sure everything works alright than you can break it before `placeholder` or `>`  . But as placeholder is large in length you have to deal with larger line of code @MarcusArnhold

Comment: I guess I will put this as answered, thanks. I was hoping that there could be a way to do something like placeholder = ["text 1" + "text 2" + "text 3"].